# How to refer jar inside my application jar without using third party tools?

Tags: java, jar, javafx

I have a JavaFX application which is referring to few jars. I need to create a runnable jar of the application. However, MANIFEST file is referring to classpath lib/*.jar. So the runnable jar is expecting the *.jar to be present under /lib folder. If the jar is moved elsewhere, it doesn't work. I'm copying these *.jar inside my runnable jar. Still it is not referring to them. Please help me to refer to the jars present inside the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in eclipse it will create a runnable jar where it will extract the classpath classes to its own jar file. If you want to combine your application jar and reference jars together you can do the same.

If runnable jar's MANIFEST refers lib/*.jar means your application structure should be

```
Main Directory
  runnable.jar
  lib
    a.jar
    b.jar
```

I don't know how it works, by copying reference jars inside runnable jar.

Comment: If I use normal ANT script generated by Eclipse, it is not extracting the reference jars.So I added a copy statement to copy the reference jars inside my executable jar. However these are not being referred. It would be great if those jars gets extracted also.

Comment: When you export in eclipse, it will ask you for the reference in `Library Handling`